# removing the some in left join RDD in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm running a left join in a Spark RDD but sometimes I get an output like this:

`(k, (v, Some(w)))`

or

`(k, (v, None))`

how do I make it so it give me back just

`(k, (v, (w)))`

or

`(k, (v, ()))`

here is how I'm combining 2 files..

```
def formatMap3(
    left: String = "", right: String = "")(m: String = "") = {
  val items = m.map{k => {
   s"$k"}}
  s"$left$items$right"
}



val combPrdGrp = custPrdGrp3.leftOuterJoin(cmpgnPrdGrp3)

val combPrdGrp2 = combPrdGrp.groupByKey

val combPrdGrp3 = combPrdGrp2.map { case (n, list) => 
  val formattedPairs = list.map { case (a, b) => s"$a $b" }
  s"$n ${formattedPairs.mkString}"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just interesting in getting formatted output without the `Somes`/`Nones`, then something like this should work:

```
val combPrdGrp3 = combPrdGrp2.map { case (n, list) => 
  val formattedPairs = list.map { 
    case (a, Some(b)) => s"$a $b" 
    case (a, None) => s"$a, ()" 
  }
  s"$n ${formattedPairs.mkString}"
}
```

If you have other uses in mind then you probably need to provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

The `leftOuterJoin()` function in Spark returns the tuples containing the join key, the left set's value and an `Option` of the right set's value. To extract from the `Option` class, simply call `getOrElse()` on the right set's value in the  resultant RDD. As an example:

```
scala> val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Array(("k1", 4), ("k4", 7), ("k8", 10), ("k6", 1), ("k7", 4)))
rdd1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[13] at parallelize at <console>:21

scala> val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Array(("k5", 4), ("k4", 3), ("k0", 2), ("k6", 5), ("k1", 6)))
rdd2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[14] at parallelize at <console>:21

scala> val rdd_join = rdd1.leftOuterJoin(rdd2).map { case (a, (b, c: Option[Int])) => (a, (b, (c.getOrElse()))) }
rdd_join: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (Int, AnyVal))] = MapPartitionsRDD[18] at map at <console>:25'

scala> rdd_join.take(5).foreach(println)
...
(k4,(7,3))
(k6,(1,5))
(k7,(4,()))
(k8,(10,()))
(k1,(4,6))
```